# cant cd to a directory error while moving files to another directory

Tags: bash

I have written the following code to MOVE ALL THE TRACE FILES CREATED BEFORE 2 MINUTES TO A SEPARATE DIRECTORY. Now when I am hard-coding the source and target path in the script, it is working fine; but when I am passing them as variable,I am getting error message. Following is my code:

```
##THIS SCRIPT WILL MOVE ALL THE TRACE FILES CREATED BEFORE 2 MINUTES TO A SEPARATE DIRECTORY
cd /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix  //MY TRACE_BKP.SH FILE EXISTS HERE
#TRACE_PATH=/home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix
#BKUP_PATH=/home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp
MINUTES=$1  #IT WILL GET THE NUMBER OF MINUTES FROM THE COMMAND LINE
TRACE_PATH=$2   #INSTEAD OF HARD-CODING TAKING PATHS AS VARIABLE
BKUP_PATH=$3    #^^
echo $MINUTES   
echo $BKUP_PATH
echo $TRACE_PATH
cd $TRACE_PATH
echo $pwd

for i in `find . -cmin +$MINUTES -name "*.trc"`  ##FINDING FILES WITH EXTENSTION .TRC WHICH ARE OLDER THAN GIVEN MINUTES
do
echo "Moving files $i, size `du -h $i`, which are older than $MINUTES minutes"
echo $i
mv $i $BKUP_PATH
done
```

I am running the code as:

```
adhikarisubir@ubuntu:~/test/basic_unix$ sh trace_bkp.sh 2 home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp
```

The error output is:

```
2
home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp
home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix
trace_bkp.sh: 11: cd: can't cd to home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix 

Moving files ./elnc.trc, size 0 ./elnc.trc, which are older than 2 minutes
./elnc.trc
mv: cannot move ‘./elnc.trc’ to ‘home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp’: No such file or directory
Moving files ./ph.trc, size 0   ./ph.trc, which are older than 2 minutes
./ph.trc
mv: cannot move ‘./ph.trc’ to ‘home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `home/` is a *relative path* - unless you are running the script from `/` you probably need `/home/...`

Comment: And, IMO, it is always best to hard code your directories in scrips with the full path. `SRC=/your/first/path ; DST=/your/dest, cp $SRC $DST`

Comment: Isn't there a better way to "process" each found file? looping over the output of find doesn't feel right... and `mv` would fail on filenames containing spaces, newlines, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rewrite:

```
#!/bin/bash

minutes=$1
trace_path=$2
bkup_path=$3

if [[ ! -d "$trace_path" ]]; then
    echo "Error: trace_path '$trace_path' is not a directory" >&2
    exit 1
fi
if [[ ! -d "$bkup_path" ]]; then
    echo "Error: bkup_path '$bkup_path' is not a directory" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Moving files which are older than $minutes minutes"
find "$trace_path" -cmin +"$minutes" -name "*.trc" -exec mv -v -t "$bkup_path" '{}' \+
```

Notes:

- you don't need to `cd` anywhere

  - if you want to change dir to where the script is, do this: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`
- always quote your `"$variables"` unless you know precisely when to leave the quotes off
- don't use UPPER_CASE_VARS: one day you'll [accidentally write `PATH=foo`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) and then wonder why your script is broken
- validate user input
- `find` can do stuff with the files it finds.
- `mv` has options, check its man page

Comment: You know, you could just run rsync every 2 minutes :)